# PHP performance drops when adding while output string to variable

Tags: php, ajax

First some general information.

My PHP runs approx 1000-1500 while loops depending on what the database returns.

Normal execution time is approx 0.3 sec. That's great :)

Now I need to load the PHP output on another page using AJAX and therefore I start adding the output to a `$html` variable in stead of just doing `echo` on it, so that it can be encoded to JSON format and send over AJAX.

I use the `$html .= some_output` for this. (this task must be done as many times as the while loop runs).

However after adding the `$html .=` in stead of `echo` the script is now taking +9 sec's to finish!!

That's clearly not optimal to the end user who is waiting for the AJAX call to return with some results.

I did some `microtime` on the code to be sure where the problem origins from - and no doubt it is the `.=` operator.

Any suggestions on how to minimize this?

EDIT: Here comes the code blocks.

First the one that loads flawlessly.

```
<?php
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    session_start();
    include "../functions/sqlsrv_connect.php";
    $skid_id = $_GET['skid_id'];
    $vendor_id = $_GET['vendor_id'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/linkcontainer.css">
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent" style="display: none;">
<?php
    $sql_get_vdm_sections = "
        SELECT
            ml2.level2_descr,
            ml2.level2_id
        FROM
            main_vdm_level2 AS ml2
        JOIN
            vdm_index AS vdm_i
        ON
            vdm_i.level2_id = ml2.level2_id
        WHERE
            vdm_i.skid_id = $skid_id
        AND
            vdm_i.vendor_id = $vendor_id
        GROUP BY
            ml2.level2_descr,
            ml2.level2_id
        ORDER BY
            ml2.level2_id
    ";
    $get_vdm_sections = sqlsrv_query($sqlsrv, $sql_get_vdm_sections);
    while($vdm_section = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_vdm_sections,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $level2_id = $vdm_section['level2_id'];
        $level2_descr = $vdm_section['level2_descr'];
?>
        <div id="S<?php echo $level2_id;?>" class="section">

            <div class="sectionhead">
                <?php echo $level2_descr;?>
            </div>

            <div class="container_holder">
                <div id="O<?php echo $level2_id;?>" class="obsolete_section">
                    <div class="obsolete_lineholder">
                        <div class="obsolete_header">
                            <div class="clmn_header">
                                <p class="small bold">Obsolete Documentation</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="obsolete_lineholder">
                        <div class="obsolete_linkholder">
                            <a href="#" class="div" target="_blank">
                                <div class="obsolete_text">
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="obsolete_lineholder">
                        <div class="obsolete_linkholder">
                            <a href="#" class="div" target="_blank">
                                <div class="obsolete_text">
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>          
                    <div class="obsolete_lineholder">
                        <div class="obsolete_linkholder">
                            <a href="#" class="div" target="_blank">
                                <div class="obsolete_text">
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="active_cnt">
                    <div class="button_holder">
                        <div class="active_btn">
                            <p class="small">Active Documentation</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="obsolete_btn">
                            <p class="small">View Obsolete Documentation</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lineholder">
                        <div class="linkholder">
                            <div class="clmn_header">
                                <p class="small bold">Chapters</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="linkholder_cnt">
<?php
        $file_verification = true;
        $sql_get_section_content = "
            SELECT
                file_verification,
                level3_head,
                level3_descr,
                level4_descr,
                doc_no,
                doc_place,
                doc_denominator,
                doc_type
            FROM
                vdm_index
            WHERE
                skid_id = $skid_id
            AND
                vendor_id = $vendor_id
            AND
                level2_id = $level2_id
            AND
                level4_descr IS NULL
        ";

        $get_section_content = sqlsrv_query($sqlsrv, $sql_get_section_content);
        $row_number = 1;

        while ($section_content = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_section_content,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $level3_file_verification = $section_content['file_verification'];
            $level3_head = $section_content['level3_head'];
            $level3_descr = $section_content['level3_descr'];
            $level3_doc_no = $section_content['doc_no'];
            $level3_doc_place = $section_content['doc_place'];
            $level3_doc_denominator = $section_content['doc_denominator'];
            $level3_doc_type = $section_content['doc_type'];

            $level3_width = 100;

            $row_id = 'S'.$level2_id.'_R'.$row_number;

            $sql_get_level4 = "
                SELECT
                    file_verification,
                    level4_descr,
                    doc_no,
                    doc_place,
                    doc_denominator,
                    doc_type
                FROM
                    vdm_index
                WHERE
                    skid_id = $skid_id
                AND
                    vendor_id = $vendor_id
                AND
                    level2_id = $level2_id
                AND
                    level3_descr = '$level3_descr'
                AND
                    level4_descr IS NOT NULL
            ";

            $get_level4 = sqlsrv_query($sqlsrv, $sql_get_level4);
            $level4_array = array();
            while ($level4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_level4,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                array_push($level4_array, $level4);
            }

            if (!empty($level4_array)){
                $level3_width -= 10;
                $level4_active = true;
            }
            else {
                $level4_active = false;
            }

            if ($file_verification != true){
                $level3_width -= 10;
                $level3_flag = true;
            }
            else {
                $level3_flag = false;
            }
?>
                        <div class="lineholder">
                            <a href="../proj_hist.pdf" class="div" target="_blank">
                                <div class="project">
<?php
            if ($level3_doc_denominator != NULL){
?>
                                    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="45px" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 45 25" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                                        <rect fill="#66FECB" width="27.1" height="25"></rect>
                                        <polygon fill="#66FECB" points="45,12.5 27,0.000 27,25.000 "></polygon>
                                    </svg>
<?php
            }
?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="project_name">
                                    <div class="project_text">
                                        <?php echo $level3_doc_denominator;?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="linkholder" >
                                <div id="<?php echo $row_id;?>" class="top_row" >
                                    <div class="projectstatus" style="background: #ffffff; width: 100%;">
                                    </div>                              
<?php
            if(!(empty($level3_head))&&empty($level3_descr)){
?>
                                        <div class="link_text level3_head" style="float: left; width: 100%; white-space: nowrap;">

                                            <?php echo $level3_head;?>
                                        </div>
<?php
            }
            else {
?>
                                    <a href="../functions/load_doc.php?doc_no=<?php echo $level3_doc_no.'&doc_place='.$level3_doc_place.'&doc_type='.$level3_doc_type.'&doc_denominator='.$level3_doc_denominator;?>" class="div" target="_blank">
                                        <div class="link_text" style="float: left; width: <?php echo $level3_width;?>%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
                                            <?php echo $level3_descr;?>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
<?php
                if($level3_flag == true){
?>
                                    <div class="flag_this">
                                    </div>
<?php
                }

                if ($level4_active == true){
?>
                                    <div id="<?php echo $row_id;?>_EXPAND" class="expand">
                                        <div class="expand_icon <?php echo $row_id;?>_EXPAND_icon">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  
<?php           }
            }
?>

                                </div>

                                <div class="clear">
                                </div>
<?php
            if ($level4_active == true) {
?>
                                <div class="<?php echo $row_id;?>_level4">
<?php
                foreach ($level4_array as $level4){
                    $level4_doc_no = $level4['doc_no'];
                    $level4_doc_place = $level4['doc_place'];
                    $level4_doc_type = $level4['doc_type'];
?>
                                    <div id="<?php echo $row_id;?>_SL1" class="sub_row <?php echo $row_id;?>_EXPAND_sub">
                                        <div class="projectstatus" style="background: #ffffff; width: 50%;">
                                        </div>
                                            <a href="../functions/load_doc.php?doc_no=<?php echo $level4_doc_no.'&doc_place='.$level4_doc_place.'&doc_type='.$level4_doc_type;?>" class="div" target="_blank">
                                                <div class="sub_link_text">
                                                    <?php echo $level4['level4_descr'];?>

                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="clear">
                                    </div>
<?php
                }
?>
                                </div>
<?php
            }
?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<?php
            $row_number++;
        }
?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
    </div>

    <div id="additional_box">
        <div id="additional_info">
            I hold additional information about this document!
        </div>

        <div id="close_additional" onclick="close_additional()">
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
       mouseX = e.pageX; 
       mouseY = e.pageY;
    });

    function additional() {
        mouseY -= 5;
        mouseX += 20;
        $('#additional_box').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
    };

    function close_additional() {
        $('#additional_box').hide();
    };

    function reset_expansion_icon(){
        var index;
        var i = document.getElementsByClassName('expand_icon');
        for (index =0; index < i.length; ++index) {
            i[index].style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/expand.png')";
        }
    }

    function reset_this_expansion_icon(me){
        var index;
        var e = $(me).children('.expand_icon')
        for (index =0; index < e.length; ++index) {
            e[index].style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/expand.png')";
        }
    }

    $('.flag_this').click(function(){
        additional();
    });

    $('.obsolete_btn').click(function() {
        $('.section').hide();

        var section = $(this).closest('.section');
        $(section).show();

        //var btn_parent = $(this).parent();
        var container = $(this).closest('.container_holder');
        var obsolete = $(container).children('.obsolete_section');

        $(obsolete).fadeIn(500);
        $('.sub_row').hide();
        reset_expansion_icon();
    });

    $('.active_btn').click(function() {
        $('.section').fadeIn(500);
        $('.obsolete_section').hide();
        $('.sub_row').hide();
        reset_expansion_icon();
    });

    $('.expand').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent('.top_row');
        var level4_class = $(parent).attr('id') + '_level4';
        var sub_row_class = $(parent).attr('id') + '_EXPAND_sub';
        var index;
        var e = document.getElementsByClassName(sub_row_class);
        var d = document.getElementsByClassName(level4_class);
        for (index = 0; index < e.length; ++index) {
            if(e[index].style.display == 'block'){
                $(d[0]).slideUp('slow');
                e[index].style.display = 'none';
            }
            else{
                d[0].style.display = 'block';
                $(e[index]).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }

        var expand_icon_class = $(parent).attr('id') + '_EXPAND_icon';
        var i = document.getElementsByClassName(expand_icon_class);
        if (e[0].style.display == 'block')
            i[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/condense.png')";
        else
            var me = $(this);
            reset_this_expansion_icon(me);
    });

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#parent').fadeIn(300);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
echo 'Total execution time in seconds: ' . (microtime(true) - $time_start);
?>
```

And the the `.=` version (html, head and body is removed as it will load on another page)

```
<?php
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    session_start();
    include "sqlsrv_connect.php";
    $skid_id = $_POST['skid_id'];
    $vendor_id = $_POST['vendor_id'];

    $html = "
        <div id='parent'>
    ";

    $sql_get_vdm_sections = "
        SELECT
            ml2.level2_descr,
            ml2.level2_id
        FROM
            main_vdm_level2 AS ml2
        JOIN
            vdm_index AS vdm_i
        ON
            vdm_i.level2_id = ml2.level2_id
        WHERE
            vdm_i.skid_id = $skid_id
        AND
            vdm_i.vendor_id = $vendor_id
        GROUP BY
            ml2.level2_descr,
            ml2.level2_id
        ORDER BY
            ml2.level2_id
    ";
    $get_vdm_sections = sqlsrv_query($sqlsrv, $sql_get_vdm_sections);
    while($vdm_section = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_vdm_sections,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $level2_id = $vdm_section['level2_id'];
        $level2_descr = $vdm_section['level2_descr'];

        $html .= "
        <div id='S$level2' class='section'>

            <div class='sectionhead'>
                $level2_descr
            </div>

            <div class='container_holder'>
                <div id='O$level2_id' class='obsolete_section'>
                    <div class='obsolete_lineholder'>
                        <div class='obsolete_header'>
                            <div class='clmn_header'>
                                <p class='small bold'>Obsolete Documentation</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='obsolete_lineholder'>
                        <div class='obsolete_linkholder'>
                            <a href='#' class='div' target='_blank'>
                                <div class='obsolete_text'>

                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='obsolete_lineholder'>
                        <div class='obsolete_linkholder'>
                            <a href='#' class='div' target='_blank'>
                                <div class='obsolete_text'>

                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>          

                    <div class='obsolete_lineholder'>
                        <div class='obsolete_linkholder'>
                            <a href='#' class='div' target='_blank'>
                                <div class='obsolete_text'>

                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>

                <div class='active_cnt'>
                    <div class='button_holder'>
                        <div class='active_btn'>
                            <p class='small'>Active Documentation</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class='obsolete_btn'>
                            <p class='small'>View Obsolete Documentation</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='lineholder'>
                        <div class='linkholder'>
                            <div class='clmn_header'>
                                <p class='small bold'>Chapters</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='linkholder_cnt'>        
        ";

        $file_verification = true;

        $sql_get_section_content = "
            SELECT
                file_verification,
                level3_head,
                level3_descr,
                level4_descr,
                doc_no,
                doc_place,
                doc_denominator,
                doc_type
            FROM
                vdm_index
            WHERE
                skid_id = $skid_id
            AND
                vendor_id = $vendor_id
            AND
                level2_id = $level2_id
            AND
                level4_descr IS NULL
        ";

        $get_section_content = sqlsrv_query($sqlsrv, $sql_get_section_content);

        $row_number = 1;

        while ($section_content = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_section_content,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $level3_file_verification = $section_content['file_verification'];
            $level3_head = $section_content['level3_head'];
            $level3_descr = $section_content['level3_descr'];
            $level3_doc_no = $section_content['doc_no'];
            $level3_doc_place = $section_content['doc_place'];
            $level3_doc_denominator = $section_content['doc_denominator'];
            $level3_doc_type = $section_content['doc_type'];

            $level3_width = 100;

            $row_id = 'S'.$level2_id.'_R'.$row_number;

            $sql_get_level4 = "
                SELECT
                    file_verification,
                    level4_descr,
                    doc_no,
                    doc_place,
                    doc_denominator,
                    doc_type
                FROM
                    vdm_index
                WHERE
                    skid_id = $skid_id
                AND
                    vendor_id = $vendor_id
                AND
                    level2_id = $level2_id
                AND
                    level3_descr = '$level3_descr'
                AND
                    level4_descr IS NOT NULL
            ";

            $get_level4 = sqlsrv_query($sqlsrv, $sql_get_level4);
            $level4_array = array();
            while ($level4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_level4,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                array_push($level4_array, $level4);
            }

            if (!empty($level4_array)){
                $level3_width -= 10;
                $level4_active = true;
            }
            else {
                $level4_active = false;
            }

            if ($file_verification != true){
                $level3_width -= 10;
                $level3_flag = true;
            }
            else {
                $level3_flag = false;
            }

            $html .= "
                        <div class='lineholder'>
                            <a href='../proj_hist.pdf' class='div' target='_blank'>
                                <div class='project'>
            ";
            if ($level3_doc_denominator != NULL){

                $html .= "
                                    <svg x='0px' y='0px' width='45px' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 45 25' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
                                        <rect fill='#66FECB' width='27.1' height='25'></rect>
                                        <polygon fill='#66FECB' points='45,12.5 27,0.000 27,25.000 '></polygon>
                                    </svg>
                ";
            }

            $html .= "
                                </div>

                                <div class='project_name'>
                                    <div class='project_text'>
                                        $level3_doc_denominator
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class='linkholder' >
                                <div id='$row_id' class='top_row' >
                                    <div class='projectstatus' style='background: #ffffff; width: 100%;'>
                                    </div>  
            ";

            if(!(empty($level3_head))&&empty($level3_descr)){

                $html .= "
                                        <div class='link_text level3_head' style='float: left; width: 100%; white-space: nowrap;'>
                                            $level3_head
                                        </div>
                ";

            }
            else {

                $html .= "
                                    <a href='../functions/load_doc.php?doc_no=$level3_doc_no&doc_place=$level3_doc_place&doc_type=$level3_doc_type&doc_denominator=$level3_doc_denominator' class='div' target='_blank'>
                                        <div class='link_text' style='float: left; width: $level3_width%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;'>
                                            $level3_descr
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                ";

                if($level3_flag == true){

                    $html .= "
                                    <div class='flag_this'>
                                    </div>
                    ";
                }

                if ($level4_active == true){

                    $html .= "
                                    <div id='$row_id_EXPAND' class='expand'>
                                        <div class='expand_icon $row_id_EXPAND_icon'>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                    ";
                }
            }

            $html .= "
                                </div>

                                <div class='clear'>
                                </div>
            ";

            if ($level4_active == true) {

                $html .= "
                                <div class='$row_id_level4'>
                ";

                foreach ($level4_array as $level4){
                    $level4_doc_no = $level4['doc_no'];
                    $level4_doc_place = $level4['doc_place'];
                    $level4_doc_type = $level4['doc_type'];
                    $level4_descr = $level4['level4_desr'];

                    $html .= "
                                    <div id='$row_id_SL1' class='sub_row $row_id_EXPAND_sub'>
                                        <div class='projectstatus' style='background: #ffffff; width: 50%;'>
                                        </div>
                                            <a href='../functions/load_doc.php?doc_no=$level4_doc_no&doc_place=$level4_doc_place&doc_type=$level4_doc_type' class='div' target='_blank'>
                                                <div class='sub_link_text'>
                                                    $level4_descr
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class='clear'>
                                    </div>
                    ";
                }

                $html .= "
                                </div>
                ";
            }

            $html .= "
                            </div>
                        </div>
            ";

            $row_number++;
        }

        $html .= "
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ";
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $total_time = $time_end - $time_start;
    $html .= 'Total execution time in seconds: ' . $total_time;
    }

    $html .= "
    </div>

    <div id='additional_box'>
        <div id='additional_info'>
            I hold additional information about this document!
        </div>

        <div id='close_additional' onclick='close_additional()'>
        </div>
    </div>
    ";

$script = "
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
       mouseX = e.pageX; 
       mouseY = e.pageY;
    });

    function additional() {
        mouseY -= 5;
        mouseX += 20;
        $('#additional_box').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
    };

    function close_additional() {
        $('#additional_box').hide();
    };

    function reset_expansion_icon(){
        var index;
        var i = document.getElementsByClassName('expand_icon');
        for (index =0; index < i.length; ++index) {
            i[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url('../img/expand.png')';
        }
    }

    function reset_this_expansion_icon(me){
        var index;
        var e = $(me).children('.expand_icon')
        for (index =0; index < e.length; ++index) {
            e[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url('../img/expand.png')';
        }
    }

    $('.flag_this').click(function(){
        additional();
    });

    $('.obsolete_btn').click(function() {
        $('.section').hide();

        var section = $(this).closest('.section');
        $(section).show();

        //var btn_parent = $(this).parent();
        var container = $(this).closest('.container_holder');
        var obsolete = $(container).children('.obsolete_section');

        $(obsolete).fadeIn(500);
        $('.sub_row').hide();
        reset_expansion_icon();
    });

    $('.active_btn').click(function() {
        $('.section').fadeIn(500);
        $('.obsolete_section').hide();
        $('.sub_row').hide();
        reset_expansion_icon();
    });

    $('.expand').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent('.top_row');
        var level4_class = $(parent).attr('id') + '_level4';
        var sub_row_class = $(parent).attr('id') + '_EXPAND_sub';
        var index;
        var e = document.getElementsByClassName(sub_row_class);
        var d = document.getElementsByClassName(level4_class);
        for (index = 0; index < e.length; ++index) {
            if(e[index].style.display == 'block'){
                $(d[0]).slideUp('slow');
                e[index].style.display = 'none';
            }
            else{
                d[0].style.display = 'block';
                $(e[index]).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }

        var expand_icon_class = $(parent).attr('id') + '_EXPAND_icon';
        var i = document.getElementsByClassName(expand_icon_class);
        if (e[0].style.display == 'block')
            i[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url('../img/condense.png')';
        else
            var me = $(this);
            reset_this_expansion_icon(me);
    });

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#parent').fadeIn(300);
    });
";

$json = array();

$json['html'] = $html;

$json['script'] = $script;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $json );
?>
```

Comment: Yes put the output in an array and on the end do `echo json_encode($myArray);`

Comment: ...or simply `echo implode('', $myArray);` if you want a string.

Comment: please include your code so we can help determine where your bottle neck is. I am also assuming its 1000-1500 while loops? not 1.0 - 1.5 (us number formating please) that is a lot.

Comment: 1000-1500 while loops is the correct number - but that's no problem when just `echo`ing the result. You want all 500 lines of code?

Comment: Must try the array approach :)

Comment: @UlrikPedersen If you add your actual code to the question people can give you real suggestions. Right now it's just guessing.

Comment: Use [output buffering](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php) which allows you to still use `echo`. For example: `ob_start(); echo 'foo'; $data = ob_get_clean();`. Using this method may be faster than manual string concatenation.

Comment: Turn on Xdebug and run the profiling dump through KCacheGrind/WinCacheGrind.  Using `microtime` does not necessarily give you an accurate view of what is going on in your scripts. Without access to your script it is difficult for us to determine what the problem is.

Comment: I can't spot the difference, and the problem is not easily reproduced since it includes code from other files as well as an unknown database... but I'm still convinced it's not the `.=` operator. I would recommend trying the output buffering method next. Your old code is much more readable than the new anyway, and converting the old code to use output buffering is a matter of inserting 2 x `ob_start()` and 2 x `ob_get_clean()`, so it can be tried in a matter of minutes...

Comment: `ob_start()` gives me a execution time around 0.3 sec - so I have choosen that as the best answer to this problem - even though it is not 100% proven that `.=` is the issue.

Comment: Another slightly off-topic note: Your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks - the user provides `skid_id`, and you do no validation on it... what if I decided to set `skid_id = (DROP TABLE main_vdm_level2)` (may not work, but you get the idea...) Assuming it's a numeric ID at least do `$skid_id = intval($_POST['skid_id']);` - same obviously goes for all other user-provided input.

Comment: I'm aware of it - but for the case of debugging i'm not implementing it before ready to deploy. But thanks for the concern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First some basic benchmarking

Actually... looking a bit more into it, the concat operator should be faster than the (often more convenient) array method...

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
$start = microtime(true);
$html = array();
for ($i=0; $i < 900000; $i++) {
    $html[] = "Line number $i\n";
}
$html_out = implode('', $html);
$time_spent = microtime(true) - $start;
printf("Array method: %ss\n", number_format($time_spent, 5));
printf("Array method md5: %s\n", md5($html_out));


unset($start);unset($html);unset($html_out);

$start = microtime(true);
$html = '';
for ($i=0; $i < 900000; $i++) {
    $html .= "Line number $i\n";
}
$time_spent = microtime(true) - $start;
printf("Concat method: %ss\n", number_format($time_spent, 5));
printf("Concat method md5: %s\n", md5($html));


unset($start);unset($html);unset($html_out);

$start = microtime(true);
ob_start();
for ($i=0; $i < 900000; $i++) {
    echo "Line number $i\n";
}
$html = ob_get_clean();
$time_spent = microtime(true) - $start;
printf("Output buffering method: %ss\n", number_format($time_spent, 5));
printf("Output buffering method md5: %s\n", md5($html));
```

Output:

```
Array method: 0.43333s
Array method md5: d3700cc66c04760d857e8bc9a986399c
Concat method: 0.21945s
Concat method md5: d3700cc66c04760d857e8bc9a986399c
Output buffering method: 0.22360s
Output buffering method md5: d3700cc66c04760d857e8bc9a986399c
```

### ...then trying to answer the question

#### Possible cause #1

I think the only reasonable explanation to your problem is lack of physical memory - when you do a plain echo (without output buffering), you don't keep much in memory - but if the strings you are concatenating are relatively long, then you may reach the limit of your physical memory when you store them in memory (no matter which method you use to do so)... so swapping could occur...?

#### Possible cause #2

On line 237 in the old code you have

```
<div id="<?php echo $row_id;?>_EXPAND" class="expand">
```

In the new code (on line 250) that becomes

```
echo "[...]<div id='$row_id_EXPAND' class='expand'>[...]"
```

Which means you are looking up a variable called `$row_id_EXPAND` - which I'm guessing doesn't exist, and therefore could cause a write operation to one or more error-logs for each iteration of the loop (and you have several of the same mistake elsewhere) This could potentially mean tens or even hundreds of thousands of lines in the error log per request `===` a lot of time spent writing all that data.

To avoid this kind of problem always encapsulate variables in `{}`, ie. make it:

```
echo "[...]<div id='{$row_id}_EXPAND' class='expand'>[...]"
```

Comment: Well it's the only thing that has changed - and doing a `microtime` multiple times through the code and a `$loop++` to keep track on the loops tells me that time increases heavy on each `$loop++` in the `.=` version.

Comment: @UlrikPedersen I've updated my answer with a possible explanation of your symptoms... how much physical memory do you have available, and how much data are we actually talking about buffering before it is sent?

Comment: The server has approx 5GB free physical memory at the moment - according to Chrome debugger the data recieved from the AJAX call is around 500kb. Will try some of the suggestions tommorow morning - for now it's home :)

Comment: LOL ... probably not the case then :p - I think it is time to reveal your actual code...

Comment: @UlrikPedersen I think I actually found your problem... Except if I am correct about it, it means you haven't looked in your error logs...!?

Comment: The php_errors.log did'nt catch that one - and the code renders correct on output so it must after all understand me. But you are absolute right about the faulty code. Not sure if it does any different, but I will try and correct it.

Comment: Wow - what a difference when doing the {$variable} - this was the actual problem!

Comment: Then you either have a huge error log laying around somewhere that you don't know about, or you are trying to log errors somewhere that you do not have write permissions. This is a huge obstacle in trying to do any kind of debugging (and the shear filesize could become a problem at some point). You should definitely solve this - hint: `echo ini_get('error_log')`

Comment: In IIS I had to set the server to "Development machine" to catch all of PHP's error - before that it did only catch errors and not warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Try ob_start() maybe.
Not actually verfied to be faster by myself but allows you to collect the results of echo from the buffer.

Example of using ob_start():

```
ob_start();
echo("Hello there!"); //would normally get printed to the screen/output to browser
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

None of the echo's will work as PHP will use a different string buffer whose results can be loaded into an array at the end. The `ob_get_clean()` will allow echo to start working again.

Hope this helps.